# How can I set this logo correct so my menu button wont dissapear in SyncFusion?

Tags: css, asp.net, blazor, syncfusion

I'm trying to build a new syncfusion blazor application and I'm having struggles placing the logo.

On top of the menu I want to display a logo instead of the project name, however when I place an image instead of just text the button will move down and it wont be visible anymore:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wthzs.png)

This is how it should be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWCf2.png)

As you can see in image 1 theres alot of unnecessarily empty space, I just want the logo + menu button to fit on 1 line and not below eachother, how can i achieve this?

This is the current code Im using:

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="fleetoverview" ><img src="/Resources/randomlogo.png" width="50%" height="70%" /></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niels,

You should not set percent value of image's width and height inside . If so, the a tag will fill the whole line and showed like your post.

In order to not effect your menu button, you could try fix logo's width and height like codes below:

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="">

<img src="/Resources/randomlogo.png" width="82" height="36" />

</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Adjust the value of width and height to get better view.